# Node-webkit app instance does not allow form input

Tags: node.js, webkit, node-webkit

When running a node-webkit app via

`nw app`

(where app is the directory with my package.json file), the window created does not allow me to enter input *at all*: not in the address bar, not in the developer console window, and not within input fields in the body of the document.

I'm running OSX 10.9 with Node 0.10.26 and version 0.9.2 of node-webkit. I've searched the internet far and wide, but am unable to find a solution (or anyone who has had this problem, even).

Here's my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "hello-world",
    "main": "index.html"
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question. If you run just `nw` without any arguments, can you type `nw:version` in the url bar and tell what it says?  Can you post a simple package.json and index.html that reproduces the problem?

Comment: As the program does not capture any input from the keyboard at all, I cannot even type nw:version in the url bar (it gets redirected to the terminal). I've added my package.json to the original question.

Comment: That's odd.  I can't reproduce anything like that.  I'm also on OSX 10.9 and using node-webkit 0.9.2, but I've never seen the behavior you're describing.  Instead of starting from the command line, can you try just double clicking on node-webkit.app in the finder?

Comment: Weird, reinstalling it did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In my case the reason was I created a symlink

```
ln -s /Applications/node-webkit.app/Contents/MacOS/node-webkit /usr/bin/nw
```

and started my app using

```
nw .
```

Starting the app with

```
/Applications/node-webkit.app/Contents/MacOS/node-webkit .
```

solved the problem.

Comment: I was executing nw from ~/Downloads. Moving nw into /Applications/ fixed it. Thanks.